# Sorted children in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new in using MongoDB. My question is do children stay sorted by id after erasing and deleting element. For example I have a DB that contains posts sorted by time. Is it true that they will be sorted by time after adding some posts in true order and erasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB inserts will present the data in natural order - the order they were inserted.  If you wish to sort the results, you can query with a sort predicate.  My recommendation is that you have a compound index created to satisfy your query filter predicate, as well as your sort criteria.  This follows the recommended E.S.R. (Equality - Sort - Range) rule.  See [MongoDB Index Best Practices](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) for details about the E.S.R. rule.